# jQuery: Select Only The Clicked Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create `Show more` functionaly in my school project. This is how my web-page looks like.

```
<div class="dataShow" style="display: none">Data ...</div>
<a href="#" class="showMore">read more</a>

<div class="dataShow" style="display: none">Data ...</div>
<a href="#" class="showMore">read more</a>

<div class="dataShow" style="display: none">Data ...</div>
<a href="#" class="showMore">read more</a>

<div class="dataShow" style="display: none">Data ...</div>
<a href="#" class="showMore">read more</a>
```

This is what I did in Jquery,

```
$('.showMore').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$('.dataShow').show();
});
```

Problem is that as i click `show more` it's showing all the Data (all divs) on web-page, not just the one clicked.

How can we do that? Thank You :) `This problem is solved by the answers given so far, but pls read the edited question.`

```
Edit:
```

How can we target a `div` before a specific `dataShow` div & not affecting other divs before other dataShow divs, something like this,

```
<div class="newData">Data ...</div>
<div class="dataShow" style="display: none">Data ...</div>
<a href="#" class="showMore">read more</a>

<div class="newData">Data ...</div>
<div class="dataShow" style="display: none">Data ...</div>
<a href="#" class="showMore">read more</a>

<div class="newData">Data ...</div>
<div class="dataShow" style="display: none">Data ...</div>
<a href="#" class="showMore">read more</a>
```

How can we target that first div `newData` specifically & hide() it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) method to get the immediate previous element.

```
$('.showMore').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // get previous sibling element
  $(this).prev().show();
});
```

```js
$('.showMore').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).prev().show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dataShow" style="display: none">Data ...</div>
<a href="#" class="showMore">read more</a>

<div class="dataShow" style="display: none">Data ...</div>
<a href="#" class="showMore">read more</a>

<div class="dataShow" style="display: none">Data ...</div>
<a href="#" class="showMore">read more</a>

<div class="dataShow" style="display: none">Data ...</div>
<a href="#" class="showMore">read more</a> This is what I did in Jquery,
```

---

**UPDATE :** Or select based on the index using [`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)(to get element based on index) and [`index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/)(to get the element index) methods.

```
// cache elements for later reference
var $show = $('.dataShow'),
  $btn = $('.showMore');

$btn.click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // get element based on clicked element index 
  $show.eq($btn.index(this)).show();
});
```

```js
var $show = $('.dataShow'),
  $btn = $('.showMore');
  
$btn.click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $show.eq($btn.index(this)).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dataShow" style="display: none">Data ...</div>
<a href="#" class="showMore">read more</a>

<div class="dataShow" style="display: none">Data ...</div>
<a href="#" class="showMore">read more</a>

<div class="dataShow" style="display: none">Data ...</div>
<a href="#" class="showMore">read more</a>

<div class="dataShow" style="display: none">Data ...</div>
<a href="#" class="showMore">read more</a> This is what I did in Jquery,
```

Comment: Thank You Sir :)

Comment: @KumarShivam : glad to help you

Comment: Sir, one more small question, How can I target a `div` before a specific `dataShow` div & not affecting other same divs before other dataShow divs?

Comment: Sir, please see the edited question!

Comment: @KumarShivam :check second approach

Comment: @KumarShivam  : you can target using index

Comment: @KumarShivam :  alternate method to get the div use , .... `$(this).prev().prev()` (prev twice ) or `$(this).prevAll('.newData').first()`

Answer (score 0):

Use `this` to specify the current element being clicked on, then use `.prev` to select the previous element.

To make sure the current `.showData` is the only one that gets displayed, hide all other `.showData`s before selecting and showing the `.prev()` one:

```js
$('.showMore').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.dataShow').hide();
  $(this).prev().show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dataShow" style="display: none">Data ...</div>
<a href="#" class="showMore">read more</a>

<div class="dataShow" style="display: none">Data ...</div>
<a href="#" class="showMore">read more</a>

<div class="dataShow" style="display: none">Data ...</div>
<a href="#" class="showMore">read more</a>

<div class="dataShow" style="display: none">Data ...</div>
<a href="#" class="showMore">read more</a> This is what I did in Jquery,
```

Comment: Sir, one more small question, How can I target a `div` before a specific `dataShow` div & not affecting other similar divs before other dataShow divs?

Comment: That's what the `prev()` method does - it selects only that particular `.dataShow` element right before the `.showMore` you clicked on.

Comment: Yes Sir, I got it :) . I've edited the question for the new problem i'm facing in `Show more`, please see the edit. I'm wondering can we target  that as well specifically?